# method change value of object passed to him

Tags: java

i have a problem with my code, 
the algorithm is correct but i don't understand why the method matrixInverse change the value of matrix.. MatrixInverse return only identity.

how can i solve?

```
public class Main {


public static void main(String[] args){

    double[][] matrix = new double[][]{{  56, 0, 0, 34, 0, 0},                  
                                        {  0, 1, 0,  0, 0, 0},
                                        {  0, 0, 1,  0, 0, 0},
                                        { 1, 0, 0,  1, 0, 0},
                                        {  0, 0, 0,  0, 1, 0},
                                        {  0, 0, 0,  0, 0, 1},
                                    };

    double[][] inverse = MathUtilities.matrixInverse(matrix);
    }
}
```

method matrixInverse:

```
public static double[][] matrixInverse(double[][] mat) throws ArithmeticException {

        if (mat.length != mat[0].length) {
            System.err.println("Matrix is not square");
            ArithmeticException e = new ArithmeticException();
            throw e;
        }

        double[][] matrix = mat;

    double[][] identity = new double [matrix.length][matrix.length];
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------
    for(int i = 0;i < matrix.length;++i)
    {
        for(int j = 0;j < matrix.length; ++j)
        {
            if(i == j)
            identity[i][j] = 1;
            else
            identity[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------
    for(int i = 0; i < matrix.length; ++i)
    {
        for(int j = i + 1 ; j < matrix.length; ++j)
        {
            double constant = matrix[j][i]/matrix[i][i];

            for(int k = 0; k < matrix.length; ++k)
            {
                matrix[j][k] = matrix[j][k] - (constant * matrix[i][k]);
                 identity[j][k] = identity[j][k] - (constant * identity[i][k]);
            }
        }
    }
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------
    for(int i = matrix.length - 1;i >= 0; --i)
    {
        for(int j = i - 1; j >= 0; --j)
        {
            double constant1 = matrix[j][i]/matrix[i][i];
            for(int k = matrix.length - 1 ; k >= 0; k--)
            {
                matrix[j][k] = matrix[j][k] - constant1 * matrix[i][k];
                identity[j][k] = identity[j][k] - constant1 * identity[i][k];
            }
        }
    }
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------
    for(int i = 0 ; i < matrix.length; ++i)
    {
        for(int j = 0;j < matrix.length; ++j)
        {
            identity[i][j]=identity[i][j]/matrix[i][i];
        }
    }
    System.out.println("The inverse matrix is");
    return identity;
    }
```

Comment: You aren't quite setting up your inversion matrix correctly. [This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Jordan_elimination#Finding_the_inverse_of_a_matrix) wikipedia article will help you out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`double[][] matrix = mat;`

At this line of code, you're assigning the reference, not copying the object. Therefore, if you change `matrix` or `mat`, you're actually changing the same object.

Comment: ok, but if i change an object inside a method, the change is visible also outside? java doesn't pass the value of reference?

Comment: Yes, the change will still be visible outside. The confusing thing is that Java passes by value, but object references are values in and of themselves so it can appear to be pass by reference.

Comment: thanks, how can i do for solve my problem?
i think i can create two cycle for where i assign every value of matrix to another double and use it inside of matrixInverse, but if matrix is very big it take time

Comment: My suggestion is to do some refactoring. Try to condense all of those different for loops together. This seems to be the only reason to be updating `matrix`. Another good idea is to make the input parameter `final double[][] mat` in order to force yourself to not change it.

Answer (score 0):

It's also worthwhile to look at [shallow vs deep copying](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/~scottm/cs307/handouts/deepCopying.htm).  A deep copy will keep your original matrix from being modified.

Comment: the problem with a deep copy is that matrix can be very big, and then the time for solve increase